# Import/Exporting between servers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 30+ servers that need frequent updates. I am fairly new to SQL so the only way I know how to push the DB from one server to another is the import/export wizard. Though when I do this it takes just over an hour to update all my servers one at a time.

I have only used the import/export wizard. I am not sure if this can be scripted or not.

Using SQL server management studio

Comment: Are you asking how to replicate data between 30 difference instances? If so, and without being rude, that isn't a task for someone new to SQL Server. Replication is not an easy task; especially between that many instances.

Comment: Frequent updates of *what*? All the data? Is it writable in all locations? How do you merge updates from different servers? If they're read-only copies, have you considered log shipping?

Comment: to explain a little better. The db has about 30 rows and 90 columns. only a couple fields may change each time. but common practice is to rename the old db to save it as a backup and push the new one to each system. i can't answer to how the structure of the table is, i didn't create it, still learning sql. No training here, i have had to teach myself everything. this is the one annoyance of my job that i believe could save a lot of time if i could automate it.